# How to make a image center in a div?

Tags: css, html

My HTML code looks like this:

```
<div class="ctn">
    <img src="some-img.jpg"/>
</div>
```

The `ctn` should be a fixed size, say, 150*150.

But the size of IMGs may bigger or smaller: 200*50, 50*200, 50*50 etc.

How do i make the image fit in the center of the `div` ? The image's proportion should not be changed.

====UPDATE====
Yes, I need both hori & vertical center.

Comment: Horizontally, vertically or both?

Comment: @Zenith, Yes, that'll be better.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could add css, to center the image both horizontally and vertically:

```
DIV.ctn {
    min-height: 150px;
    min-width: 150px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle }
```

...

```
<div class="ctn">
    <img src="some-img.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Edit: for details see: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.html

Comment: cool, though it worked for me when  i removed 'display: table-cell' property.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
text-align: center;    
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Kr9fV/1/)

Comment: That only centers horizontally

Answer (score 2):

i think this is your answer

```
.container img { width: 100%;}
.container {display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RUQAM/1/

it **fits**, in the **center** of your **fixed size div**, and image proportions are **not** changed.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: re-reading, you want the image size to be fixed.

```
div.cnt {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    min-height: 150px;
    min-width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way should be :

```
div.cnt {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

<div class="ctn" style="background: url('some-img.jpg') 50% 50% no-repeat;">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `ctn` has to be a fixed sized (ex: 150x150) and the image has to be proporcional and not bigger than that div, this is a solution:

**CSS**

```
.ctn{
    background-color:#F00;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
}
.ctn div{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
}
.ctn div img{
    width:150px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="ctn">
<div>
    <img src="url" />
</div>
</div>
```

This way will center the div in the middle of the screen and the image will not be bigger than 150x150 but it will mantain its proporcionality.

Answer (score 0):

Give id to your  like 
then in your css →

```
#foto{
    margin-left:180px;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

set style="margin-let:auto; margin:right:auto"

also specify width to the image else it will not work