# How to center horizontal scrolls for small screens

Tags: css, scroll

I am having problem in making a screen center for small screens

I've created 1500px wide long page designed in photoshop and sliced into tables.

i used the following code to center my page

```
width:1500px;
margin: 0 auto ;
position:relative;
```

to make it center , its good on big screens but in small screens a horizontal scrolls appears and its all to left i want to in middle as a default and i can remove it using overflow x hidden.

Comment: could you please attach link for this project/code sample

Comment: https://goo.gl/ugNHgn

File attachment

Answer (score 0):

Your  applying a static width to page, so if your viewing in small screen, page gets overflow, so in this case you have to adjust the page width with respect to screen resolution. It can be done by using media query, refer the below link about media query - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

use your CSS code with different static width in different resolution like

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .smallerscreen{
    width:1500px;
    margin: 0 auto ;
   position:relative;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 300px) {
  .smallerscreen{
    width:500px;
    margin: 0 auto ;
   position:relative;
  }
}
```

---

After reviewing your code, you have go with max-width instead of width in container class as said by Neel.

```
.container12 { max-width: 1500px;}
```

Also set image width as 100% as like in below code.

```
div[id^="index-"] > img[id^="index_"] {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but it didnt work , i've attached my file above , hope you that can make it easy .

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code is, you used  tag and gave width of **1500**(not dynamic) also i got containers(**#index-07_,#container12**) with style of

```
width : 1500px
```

instead of using

```
max-width:1500px
```

change them also add style(obviously not good choice; you may choose specific image tag but for quick fix it will work for you)

```
img{width:100%}
```

i hope it may worked for you

Comment: Sorry , didn't work . i can start from scratch .

which is the best way to keep the images in center in all monitors. 

or keep it edge to edge to any monitor , it had to be dynamic . 

like this http://josefrakichfitness.com/

But i have to do only with images which should be easy

Comment: @user3045499 if you are going to start from scratch then use any block structure(prefered **<div>**)  with **background-image** style, because background image easily manipulated by basic css. refer this links [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html), [stackoverflow.com/questions/16818192](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818192/how-to-make-a-image-center-in-a-div)